# Downloading all folders and its contents(files) from a website and uploading to another site?

Tags: c#-4.0, web, download, directory

I am working on a problem where I have to login to a website (through a form on the webpage), which has many folders displayed on the page and these folders contains many files under them.DO I understand correctly that these folders are not same as folders present on our PC which has a physical location? These folders on the website are just a link which opens a list of files upon clicking.

So, I am struggling to write a code which can login to the site and download all folders and the contents(files) and arrange it in same fashion on the PC in the same hierarchy in which it is arranged in the website. I am thinking about using httpwebrequest for logging in the site, but I have no idea how to download the folders and the contents in the same form as in website.

can anyone help me to develop the code?? I am using C# as my language with .net 4.0

Comment: The folders on the website _might_ be actual folders on the server, or they might just have the links and URLs arranged to look that way. There's no way to tell (unless you can use ftp, which I'm assuming you can't). Does Windows have a program like `wget` in unix? Try searching for that, because I think it can do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Before thinking about reinventing the wheel, why not ask your hosting provider about ftp access to the site. If you have that then problem solved ... use one of the numerous ftp clients to download all the website content in one click.

Good luck